# android #include/import source code in class

Tags: android

The Backstory: I have created an application that will read the schema from DBDesigner and build out my database connectors files which include a record file, a record object file, the queries and the create db/tables files. it is a nice little program that saves me hours in building out and managing the database. However it only creates the generic connectors and when it is regenerated it overwrites the previous files.

The Question: i am starting to get into some complex queries and was curious if there is a way to import code from another file into the class that will be picked up at compile time?

Comment: "build out my database connectors files" -- few people here will have experience with DBDesigner, and so few people will know what these files are. I recommend that you edit your question, provide examples of these files, and explain in greater detail what "import code from another file into the class" means in the context of those files.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support any kind of source import (like, say, the CSS `@import` directive). You have two options. First, you can simply copy over the code you need using your favorite editor. This is often the simplest and quickest solution.

The second option is usually more work, but it has several advantages. It involves encapsulating the useful behavior you want to import in one or more classes with a well-thought-out API for accessing the functionality and data. The biggest advantage is that it adheres to the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) ("don't repeat yourself"). In other words, if you've worked out a great solution to something, make it reusable and then just reuse it. This pays handsome dividends when you use it the third, fourth, and more times. The other big benefit is that if you discover a flaw or a possible improvement, you only need to address it in one place, rather than everywhere that you've copied the code.